# How to add and remove dynamic list and show on dynamic tab page c#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a dynamic list and dynamic tab page in my code i want to add item's into the list and show them in to the dynamic tab page

```
List<dynamic> DynList = new List<dynamic>();
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
TabPage t1 = new TabPage();

t1.Text = name;
dgv.DataSource = stufflist;
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(t1);
t1.Controls.Add(dgv);
runtimecreatedatagridview = new DataGridView();
runtimecreatedatagridview.Size = new Size(590, 200);
runtimecreatedatagridview.Location = new Point(327, 420);
this.Controls.Add(runtimecreatedatagridview);
t1.ResumeLayout();
t1.Refresh();
```

I have a sample stufflist and I want to use dynamic list Instead that and I want that dynamic list be public to use in all function of my code